# Retrieving the first value of the column to a variable in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have these 3 tables `Customer`, `Link` & `Customer_link`.

I am using the following query to retrieve the `customer_no` column from `Customer` which has values that are not available in the `customer_no` of the table `Customer_link`:

```
SELECT c.customer_no 
FROM CUSTOMER c 
LEFT JOIN Customer_link cl 
       ON c.customer_no = cl.customer_no 
WHERE cl.customer_no IS NULL
```

The table `Customer_link` has the following columns:

```
ID (generated automatically using a sequence)
Customer_no (linked to Customer table)
Link_no (linked to the Link table)
Maker_id
```

What I'm trying to do is, use the above query to get the `customer_no` from the `Customer` table that are not added to the table `Customer_link` yet (this is a constraint since `Customer_link` cannot have the same `customer_no` twice in the table which is unique. Same goes for `link_no` as well) & a similar query to get the `link_no` from the `Link` table.

Then use a `link_no` & a `customer_no` from the respective results & add then to the table `Customer_link` (there is already a function for this which I will need to call with the values that I get in the result).

I need to use a loop here so that I can update the results after adding a value from each table to the table `Customer_link` which will so that I do not get an error trying to add the same `customer_no` or `link_no` twice to the table.

Using a cursor is one way I found on the internet. But it's not very clear to me.

So what I'm trying to do exactly here is get the result for unused customer_no from `Customer` & Link_no from `Link` & insert the values in row1 is the respective columns in the table `Customer_link` & loop over to update the results & get the values in row1 again to add them as parameter to the function that I call

Comment: Also the tables are all already created. what the function(the one that i need to call) does is, it take the values that i feed it, verify from the tables(Customer & Link) & then add it to the table Customer_link along with the other required values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to get this working with the use of a cursor. I will be putting up the solution here so that someone else may need help with this.

I created a variable `cust` that was of the type Customer.Customer_no

`cust Customer.Customer_no%type;`

I then created a Cursor to be able to add the values of unused customer number to

`Cursor cr_cust
 IS
 select c.customer_no into cust from CUSTOMER c LEFT JOIN Customer_link cl on c.customer_no = cl.customer_no where cl.customer_no is null;`

Now i used a loop to get these all working this way

`begin
FOR i IN cr_cust LOOP  --to loop through the rows
      cust := i.customer_no;  --to add the value of corresponding row to the variable --cust 
      IF j <= 5 THEN  --this for getting the values from link table & assigning them to --variable so that the variables can be passed to the required function
         {code for assigning values to variables & the function calling go here}
         j:=j+1;  --to get the next value in link table
      END IF;
      IF j > 5 THEN  --exit if 5 customers have been added to the Customer_link table & --there is no need for more links to be fetched from link table
          EXIT;
      END IF;
END LOOP;
end`

Answer (score 0):

i think it doesn't require loop just follow this step

1) Insert all customer_no that not in Customer_link into **#temp** table

```
select c.customer_no into #temp from CUSTOMER c LEFT JOIN Customer_link cl on c.customer_no = cl.customer_no where cl.customer_no is null
```

2)insert Customer_no into Customer_link

```
insert into Customer_link(customer_no)
select customer_no from #temp
```

Comment: I suppose not. The table Customer_link has multiple columns that need to have values as well. hence the loop so that i can add in the mandatory values along with the required customer number. So i would need something that will let me copy only the 1st value of the resulting column

Comment: `select c.customer_no into #temp ...` is invalid for Oracle (or standard SQL). To create a new table based on a select you need to use `create table ... as select ...` in Oracle (and standard SQL). Plus there is no need for a temporary table at all. `insert into customer_link (customer_no) select ... ` will work with the original select.

Comment: i don't have idea about oracle but in sql i have done this servel time

Comment: You haven't done this "*in SQL*", you have done this in "**SQL Server**" - big difference. "SQL" is a query language not a DBMS product

Comment: pardon it's SQL SERVER @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop. Just use the select as a source for the insert:

```
insert into customer_link (customer_no)
select c.customer_no 
from customer c 
  left Customer_link cl ON c.customer_no = cl.customer_no 
where cl.customer_no is null;
```

Or alternatively use a NOT EXISTS query which is sometimes faster:

```
insert into customer_link (customer_no)
select c.customer_no 
from customer c 
where not exists (select * 
                  from customer_link cl
                  where cl.customer_no = c.customer_no);
```

Both statements will only select (and insert) unique values (i.e. no duplicates) for the `customer_no` column assuming `customer_no` is the primary key in the `customer` table.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it makes more sense now :) I might have put it across differently than i needed

Answer (score 0):

Which is the first value from `customer_no`? I guess in such kind of order.

This query will add only the first value returned (`rownum =1`) with customer_no in the specified order (`ORDER BY c.customer_no`), if you don't need the values ordered just remove the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
INSERT INTO customer_link (customer_no)
SELECT  customer_no 
  FROM (
         SELECT c.customer_no 
           FROM CUSTOMER c 
      LEFT JOIN Customer_link cl 
             ON c.customer_no = cl.customer_no 
          WHERE cl.customer_no IS NULL
       ORDER BY c.customer_no
       ) sub
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

You can find a demo I have prepared here in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79a48/1).

**EDIT:** After the changes in your question, I think you are looking for something like:

```
  INSERT INTO customer_link (customer_no, link_no)
    SELECT  customer_no,
            your_function(customer_no)
      FROM (
             SELECT c.customer_no 
               FROM CUSTOMER c 
          LEFT JOIN Customer_link cl 
                 ON c.customer_no = cl.customer_no 
              WHERE cl.customer_no IS NULL
           ) sub
```

This takes all the `customer_no` not already present in Customer_link and put them in that table with the link_no returned by your function.

Comment: I have edited the question now. Looks like I put it across totally wrong. I hope it makes more sense now :)